# Manually instantiate ActiveRecord models and their relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have T-SQL (or a stored proc) that returns records from multiple tables (using DBI perhaps), is there a way for me to manually instantiate the ActiveRecord models and their associations?  Obviously, I’m after database performance here.  I would like to be able to build my own object hierarchy (models and their relationships), but when I’m all done I would expect each model to behave normally.  That is, I am hoping this would be accomplished without some hack that might cause my structure to behave oddly.

EDIT:

This is a little contrived but it does illustrate how one query could return data n levels deep (where "n" has only practical limits) and return everything in one call to the database:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
  WHERE id = 1;

SELECT * FROM orders 
  WHERE customer_id = 1;

SELECT * FROM lineitems 
  WHERE order_id IN (
  SELECT id FROM orders 
    WHERE customer_id = 1
  );
```

And then having all of the records I would simply map the associations myself.  The problem with doing this via ActiveRecord and :include is that it will hit the database multiple times instead of just once--which is more taxing as "n" increases.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to take the results of a SQL query and instantiate the ActiveRecord objects from them?

Comment: Yes and also the associations.

Comment: Your last query doesn't actually return orders and customer if you look closely, it just return lineitems. And if you need this 3 queries to get the assosciations, it's the same as using :include with ActiveRecord

Comment: We do this sort of thing all the time at work and for each SELECT it returns a result set.  The difference with this approach and :include is that the above example makes only 1 roundtrip and not 3 and so is faster.

Comment: Mind you, you usually have to call some method on your result set object to give you the next result set.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're getting at, you're trying to execute multiple sql queries at once and still have Rails return all the instantiated models as it normally would.

What you really want is:

```
Customer.find(:all, :include => {:orders => :lineitems})
```

Which will fetch all the records your interested in in a single query and create the AR objects properly.

Comment: I should add, anything more complicated than that (like stored procedures) is probably wasting your time.  It sounds like you're trying to optimize prematurely.  You're going to spend all your time fussing over a few milliseconds here or there (which probably wont matter, anyway) and never finish/launch a product.

Comment: You're right--I have given up on premature optimization.  I have some structures that can't really be handled by the :include option, because of multiple levels of polymorphic relationships.  Take your example.  What if "orders" was a polymorphic object which sometimes has lineitems and sometimes not?  This is not a great example, I admit, however in doing the same, I've rendered :include useless.

Comment: This is a few years old now, but I'm in a similar boat where I have an existing application where queries are taking upwards of thirty seconds on page load and it is definitely a problem. I could reduce this massively by tidying up the SQL but I can't see a way around this on the ActiveRecord side.

Comment: @glenatron: Kind of out of scope, but make sure you're defining indexes. ActiveRecord is flexible enough to do much SQL you can dream up.

Comment: @StevenSoroka - all the regular database stuff is fairly solid, the problem I am seeing is that we have deep tree hierarchies and then tree members have many further relations. This does make me wonder if there is a way I could adjust the data models so that, for example, everything knew it's ultimate parent and therefore one could pull all the records in a single sweep. That might be a smart bit of re-architecting in this case. Might make an interesting Programmers.se question.